# how to remove img link and replace it

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I want to link all of my wordpress posts image link to : http://www.simafun.com Except some picture.

So i use find this code :

```php
<?php
function wpguy_linked_image($content){

    $searchfor = '/(<img[^>]*\/>)/';
    $replacewith = '<a target="_blank" href="'.get_permalink().'">$1</a>';

    {
        $content = preg_replace($searchfor, $replacewith, $content, -1);
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'wpguy_linked_image');
?>
```

It replaces all pictures link but without removing Previous link of pictures .

1. I what first remove Previous link. for example : 
   my image linked to itself
   "http://www.up.simafun.com/2013/01/police-tabriz-1.jpg"
   then raplce it by my site name(http://www.simafun.com)
2. I want exclude some picture from changing link for example a picture that linked to download (for example : "http://up.simafun.com/download-simafun.com.gif")

Excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<img.*src="(.*?)".*\/?>/",'<img src="http://up.simafun.com/download-simafun.com.gif">',$html );
```